# Add custom button to last column in every row in jquery DataTable

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, datatables

I am trying to recreate the example DataTable found here [Child Rows DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

DataTables is working fine, I am not getting the - "Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0, column 4" ERROR.
My problem is that the button is not rendering in the last column. Can somebody help me resolve this issue, Thanks!

Here is my java servlet logic..
[image]

Javascript Code:
[image]

And my Table -

```
                                <tr>
                                    
                                     <th>Employee</th>
                                     <th>Shift</th>
                                     <th>Start Date</th>
                                     <th>End Date</th>  
                                     <th>Details</th>
                                </tr>
                           </thead>
                           <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                    
                                     <th>Employee</th>
                                     <th>Shift</th>
                                     <th>Start Date</th>
                                     <th>End Date</th>
                                     <th>Details</th>
                    
                           </tr>
                           
                           </tfoot>
```

Comment: In the render function, you need to return a **string**. So you only need to add a single quote before and after your button definition, like this `'<button>Click Here!</button>';`. And please, next time try to include your code (just as you did with your HTML code), instead of pictures.

Comment: Now that you confirmed that it worked, I've just added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the render function, you need to return a string. So you only need to add a single quote before and after your button definition, like this `'<button>Click Here!</button>';`

Comment: Now only the clicked button appears, and no other data. Is there something more I need to do than "{data: "Employee"}

Comment: I figured that part out, needed to change my response from the servlet, thanks!